# "[Errno 2]" No such file or directory

Tags: python, file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\*\Documents\GitHub\_Testes\novo_teste.py", line 1, in <module>
    teste = open('teste.txt', 'w')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'teste.txt'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't create the file and instead returns this error

I already tried 'w', 'w+', 'x', 'x+'. It simply only accepts if I use the absolute path, shouldn't it accept using the script directory as a base?

I tried using 'os.getcwd()':

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())  # Show the actual directory
arquivo = open(os.getcwd()+"\\teste.txt", "w")
arquivo.write('teste')
arquivo.close()
```

result:

```
PS C:\Users\*\Documents\GitHub\_Testes> & C:/Users/*/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/_Projetos/_Testes/testes.py
C:\Users\*\Documents\GitHub\_Testes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\_Projetos\_Testes\testes.py", line 3, in <module>
    arquivo = open(os.getcwd()+"\\teste.txt", "w")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\*\\Documents\\GitHub\\_Testes\\teste.txt'
```

Comment: I would expect it to create the `teste.txt` file in the directory you run the script from. Since it can't, there might be a problem with write permissions to that directory, or it has a strange name. In your error message the script seems to be getting run from `c:\Users\*\Documents`. Is * in the actual error message, or did you just use it to hide your username?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check the linked duplicates. If they don't address the problem, at least make sure you understand how to check the *current working directory*, and thus get the needed information in order to understand what is going on. If there is still an issue then please try to create a [mre] (in this case, that would include steps for running the code).

Comment: @Adam I already tried to create the file in another folder, changing the script and it gave the same error, the strangest thing is that a long time ago it worked normally, is it something from python 3.11?
And yes I used * to hide the user, sorry

Answer (score -1):

This is because from where you're calling (python novo_teste.py) it cannot find the file where you are (check if the path exist). You probably calling this from another directory.
If you want understanding or visualize the actual directory, do this:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()) # Show the actual directory
print(os.listdir()) # Show all files and folder on it
file = open("teste.txt", "w")
```

Comment: StackOverflow is an English only site.